# How do I ensure that LaTeX displays all the characters in in-text citations?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I've currently got the following bibtex reference:

```
Such an example of this is the Paris Agreement, a 2015 global initiative with 196 member countries which aims to reduce global warming to below 1.5\degree C and set ambitious but feasible targets for countries to combat GHG emissions \cite{UNFCCC_2020}.
```

With bibliography citation: `\@misc{UNFCCC_2020, title={The Paris Agreement}, url={https://unfccc.int/process-and-meetings/the-paris-agreement/the-paris-agreement}, journal={UNFCCC}, publisher={United Nations Climate Change}, year={2020}}`

However upon compilation I only obtain this:
[image]

Which clearly is missing "CCC" following the "UNF" bit. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a compilable TeX code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: what do you mean by "clearly missing" here? `UNFCCC_2020` is just the internal identifier used by `\cite` to reference this entry. It never appears in the document except fordebugging.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: So I'm relatively new to this form of citing as I used to do it manually (enter the in-text citation as text and copy paste the references onto a reference section). I will add context for the .bib file citation on the original post.

Comment: the label depends on the citation/bibliography style you are  using. So show a complete example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought that the UNFCCC_2020 was implying that "UNFCCC" was the name that would appear cited, with the underscore used to separate the date which would follow after. For example: \cite{Smith_2020} -> (Smith, 2020). I must be getting something wrong

Comment: @Nico.H no the cite key is usually not used and the short form is constructed from author initials and date but the exact rule depends on the style that you are using about which you have given no information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're aiming to create an authoryear-style citation call-out, yet the entry is missing an `author` field.

The most natural fix consists of actually providing/backfilling an `author` field. Would changing

```
journal={UNFCCC}
```

to

```
author={UNFCCC}
```

be acceptable to you? If `{UNFCCC}` isn't descriptive enough, you could use `{{United Nations Framework Convention on Climate Change}}`, right? (The doubled set of curly braces serves to inform BibTeX that's it's dealing with a "corporate" author and hence shouldn't try to find the first name, von, and surname components of an "ordinary" name.) Be sure to recompile your document suitably after modifying the field type of this entry.

Remark: All BibTeX bibliography styles I've ever come across ignore the `journal` field for *all* entry types *except* the `@article` entry type. Since you've chosen the `@misc` entry type for the entry at hand, you wouldn't be losing any degrees of freedom by making the switch suggested above.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{UNFCCC_2020, 
  title  = {{The Paris Agreement}}, 
  url    = {https://unfccc.int/process-and-meetings/the-paris-agreement/the-paris-agreement}, 
  author = {UNFCCC}, 
  publisher={United Nations Climate Change}, 
  year   = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document} 

\cite{UNFCCC_2020}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Like I said I'm very much new to this form of "automatized" citation so I'm very inexperienced. Thank you for your help and patience, I will be sure to take note of your remark too

Comment: @Nico.H - You're most welcome!